# Flexbox dynamic layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am coding a layout that I managed to achieve it by Grid but I don't know how can I do it in FlexBox. The reason I want to do it in FlexBox is because IE-11 does not support Grid properly.

To make it simpler lets only think about `xs` screens and I the fact that I have 6 cards:

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="card1" > card 1 </div>
  <div class="card2" > card 2 </div>
  <div class="card3" > card 3 </div>
  <div class="card4" > card 4 </div>
  <div class="card5" > card 5 </div>
  <div class="card6" > card 6 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have such a structure so I can add and remove cards `dynamically` and layout automatically changes based on the number of cards within it.

The default size of the card is always to it's container `width` which means if I have one card it will be full width.

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="card1" > card 1 </div>
</div>
```

if I have two card the width will be divided between them: Kind of like `flex-grow`

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="card1" > card 1 </div>
  <div class="card2" > card 2 </div>
</div>
```

The problem with `flex-grow` is I cannot control how they get stacked. if you think about the 6 card problem in a `xs` screen I want them to be stacked in `3 row` of `2 card each` and I cannot break them with `flex-grow`

So if I go to `medium screen` size I want them to be in `2 row of 3 cards` and `xs screen => 3 row, 2 cards`

I know that flex is one directional but hope there are tricks and tips that I haven't heard. I have a `codepen` example here at https://codepen.io/jamie-jamier/pen/yLewWqy but it is not quite what I like, If you resize the screen to `500px` you can see with `flex-wrap` it becomes `1 card per row`

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding of your requirements, I have modified your CSS a bit and added a media query for medium size screen. See if it fits your requirements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  height: 300px; 
}

.card1 { background-color: lemonchiffon; }
.card2 { background-color: lightblue; }
.card3 { background-color: mediumspringgreen; }
.card4 { background-color: khaki; }
.card5 { background-color: orchid; }
.card6 { background-color: darkgray; }

/* Medium devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  } 
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card card1"> card 1 </div>
  <div class="card card2"> card 2 </div>
  <div class="card card3"> card 3 </div>
  <div class="card card4"> card 4 </div>
  <div class="card card5"> card 5 </div>
  <div class="card card6"> card 6 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

until this time, i can't think on this whitout some js, something to count the elements and apply differents styles, something like this:

```js
var cards = $('.card').length;

if(cards <= 1){
  $('.card').addClass('justOne');
}else if(cards <=2){
  $('.card').addClass('twoCards');
}else{
  $('.card').addClass('moreThanTree');
}
```

```css
.card { 
  height: 300px;
}

.justOne{
  width: 100%;
}

.twoCards{
  width: 50%
}

.moreThanTree{
  width: 33.333%;
}

.card1 { background-color: lemonchiffon; }
.card2 { background-color: lightblue; }
.card3 { background-color: mediumspringgreen; }
.card4 { background-color: khaki; }
.card5 { background-color: orchid; }
.card6 { background-color: darkgray; }


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .card {
    background-color: blue;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="card card1" > card 1 </div>
  <div class="card card2" > card 2 </div>
  <div class="card card3" > card 3 </div>
  <div class="card card4" > card 4 </div>
  <div class="card card5" > card 5 </div>
  <div class="card card6" > card 6 </div>
  <div class="card card5" > card 7 </div>
  <div class="card card6" > card 8 </div>
</div>
```

Check this pen based on yours(using jQuery):

https://codepen.io/francisco2016/pen/bGEZyQJ